# Does the iOS SDK give access to the Calendar picker used by iPhone's built-in Calenar app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, calendar, eventkit

I've dug around a bit in the Eventkit/EventkitUI docs and couldn't find an answer.  Does the iOS SDK provide a way to display the Calendar chooser view that the built-in Calendar app uses when you want to move an event to a different calendar?  If not, what would be the best way to build that?  How do I know which account each calendar is from?  How do I display the little color dot?  Are there any 3rd party libraries that provide something like this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Specifically I'm asking about this screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the UI for free, but you can get a list of the user's calendars with an [`EventStore`'s `Calendar` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/calendars).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot distinguish between the calendar events. They all belong to one calendar by default. Event Kit only allows you to add, edit events on the default calendar. And you will need to use either third party calendar to replicate the UI or you will need to create your own. The question link given by Vagrant seems to be answering about the third party calendars.

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal is the most fav.