# Drawing on UIButtons

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drawing

I'm currently writing an app that has a calendar as one of it's screens.
For the calendar I need to place coloured circles under the numbers to represent activities on those days.

I was leaning towards the UIButton's for each day in the calendar so that I could assign the same functionality to all the buttons {including customised drawing routines to handle the coloured circles on each day).

Is it possible to draw coloured circles in on the fly or should I use pre-made images up to a certain number of events (coloured circles)?

Secondly, if I can draw these on the fly, can someone point out the documentation for the classes involved for me to do this?

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385900/does-the-ios-sdk-give-access-to-the-calendar-picker-used-by-iphones-built-in-ca

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Most of these links involve using the built in calendars or other custom libraries for creating calendars which is good but doesn't fit what I'm trying to achieve. I'm ok with calculating what I need to display, I just need to know how to do the customised drawing on each day number in a month view calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is `(UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(CGRect)rect`.

The documentation for the class can be found at [UIBezierPath Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBezierPath)